# Remove Tabs from TabControl Where Index is Not

Tags: c#, indexing, tabcontrol

I am trying to remove all tabs from a `TabControl` where the tab index is not a specified index.

I have this so far:

```
for (int i = tabcontrolOptions.TabCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (i != tabNo)
    {
        tabcontrolOptions.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

But that removes all tabs, and not the specified tabNo.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>When you remove a tab, the tabs get reindexed</s>.  Actually, what you're doing shouldn't be affected by that. But try the below anyway, maybe it will help.

Refer to the tab object explicitly, not by index:

```
var tabToKeep = tabcontrolOption.TabPages[tabNo];
for (int i = tabcontrolOptions.TabCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (tabcontrolOption.TabPages[i] != tabToKeep)
    {
        tabcontrolOptions.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works as expected, so thank you.  My only issue is that I am trying to call this in a method in the form, so it appears to have no affect.  If I put it in the OnLoad it works fine, but not in the method :(

Comment: What do you mean by "in the method"? Is this a method on the form? Where is it being called from?

Comment: Yes the method is in the form and being called from a class by creating a new instance of the form.

Comment: Can you share your code? Perhaps post a new question with the details, and put a link here. I'll take a look, and others will see it too.